# How to make two linux VMs to communicate each other

Tags: networking, virtual-machines

I have Dell laptop with Windows 11 OS is running. I want to run two light weight Linux machines as VM on top of it so that I did following action items.

- I installed *ubuntu 20.04* via *WSL 2*. Its server name is **foo** and IP address is **192.168.149.xxx**
- I installed *centos 7* via *Oracle VM VirtualBox*. Its server name is **bar** and its IP address is **192.168.1.xxx**
- I selected **Bridged adapter** in the networking settings from *Oracle VM VirtualBox*. Tutorial I was following a guy selected that option without much of explanation.
- I added **192.168.1.xxx bar** entry on *C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts* file.

When I ran `ping 192.168.1.xxx` to verify connectivity from *foo* to *bar*, it returned bytes and I believe *foo* is aware of *bar*.

```
64 bytes from gitlab (192.168.1.xxx): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=1.60 ms
64 bytes from gitlab (192.168.1.xxx): icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.630 ms
```

The problem is when I ran `ping 192.168.149.xxx` from *bar* in order to verify connectivity to *foo*, it didn't return any bytes but hung which I believe no connection to *foo*.  After a while, I terminated its execution by pressing *Ctrl-C*, it returned `449 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 448452ms`.

I looked up/read https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html to understand how *Oracle VM VirtualBox* network setting does.

[image]

I tried also with **NAT** then it behaved reversed way. From *bar* to *foo*, `ping` worked but not from *foo* to *bar*.

I am new to networking and Linux. Although I read aforementioned document but not having a good understanding of it unfortunately.  My goal is both servers be able to aware of each other and execute remote commands between.

I'd appreciate greatly if anyone can guide me how to make these two VMs to work together in network context.

**Update**:

From windows platform, I opened up CMD and checked its IP config with `ipconfig` cmd.

```
Ethernet adapter VirutalBox Host-Only Network:
IPv4 Address ....... 192.168.aaa.bbb

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:
IPv4 Address ....... 192.168.ccc.ddd

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL)
IPv4 Address ....... 192.168.eee.hhh
```

Then I ran `ping` cmd from VM **bar** server for all three IPs but **none worked out**. After watching a tutorial on *Oracle VM VirtualBox* networking configuration with **Bridged adapter**, I like to believe first IP among three, should have worked.

```
host (windows) ---> bar (vm) good

bar            ---> host     failed
```

Comment: From the little experience I have had with WSL2, the networking was implemented in an odd way, and the implementation could prevent communication from outside to the WSL2. Bridging should work fine on Virtualbox side.

Comment: my apology for late late reply. I appreciate sharing your advice!

Answer (score 1):

Probably a netmask issue.
Bring the IP address of foo within 192.168.1 range.

Comment: I appreciate your advice. Watching more tutorials of Oracle VM VirtualBox networking settings, I think your suggest may work however above IPs are all dynamically assigned. I am not sure how to make them as static.  More reading coming for myself.

Comment: If you select bridging and let your normal (outside VirtualBox) DHCP server give your VM an IP, your problem should be solved. (I hope)